# save handsontable to persistent state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handsontable

I have created a table using handsontable:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: [],
        dataSchema: {id: null},
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 1,
        colHeaders: ["Car"],
        columns: [
          {data: 'id'}
        ],
        rowHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        persistentState: true,
        onChange: function (change, source) {
            console.log(change);
            console.log(source);
        }
      });
```

They have a pretty elaborate [example](http://docs.handsontable.com/tutorial-load-and-save.html#page-onchange) on saving/loading to/from server using ajax. However, I just want use persistent state to save load all the stuff.

In particular I want when a cell's value in hot is changed I want to save this information in some local storage, so that I can retrieve it later. The closest I got was to use `change` parameter in onChange and save it manually to localStorage. My main question is how can I save cell's info once it changed to some local storage? Better to persistentStorage.

Also, can I save the whole `hot` table to local storage? What is more efficient to update the whole table every time, or to update just the value of that particular cell? Is there a quick way to load table? Can you provide a good example how can I save/load table to local storage *on change*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, I went with something like this:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: [],
        dataSchema: {id: null},
        startCols: 4,
        colHeaders: ["ID"],
        columns: [
          {data: 'id'}
        ],
        rowHeaders: true,
        minSpareRows: 4,
        afterChange: function (change, source) {
            // restore table after reload of a page
            if (source === "loadData") {
                // load data from local storage
                if (localStorage['data']) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage['data'])
                    this.loadData(data);
                    this.render();
                    return
                }

            }
            else {
                // save all data to local storge if the edit happends
                localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(this.getData());
                return
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great answer. Thx @Sergey.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing what you ask so you'll have to try it out and see. The most common way to do what you ask is to get the data `onAfterChange`. In this callback (read the documentation) you have access to the new value and the row and col indeces. At that point, you can do one of two things:

You can store in `localStorage` the `(row,col)` with the data at that position. That's the first option. Then onLoad you can go through all available key,value pairs and set the data array.

The second thing you can do is much easier but more costly. In the `onAfterChange` callback, every time, save the contents of `hot.getData()`. You can do it like this:

```
// assuming 'hot' is the name of your handsontable instance
localStorage["data"] = hot.getData()
```

Storing each cell is fast and takes minimal space on saving (so this part will be fast) but it's harder to implement the loading code. The storing of all the data might take longer but it makes your code much easier to implement (on load, simply set the `data` object to the value of `localStorage.data`).

I would try the storing of all the data first (on the largest data set you think you'll ever have) and seeing if it is slow. If it is, use the per-cell approach.

EDIT: persistent state taken from [documentation](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options)

The following is the direct quotation. The difference here from what I posted earlier is that instead of doing `localStorage["data"] = hot.getData()` you would instead do `hot.persistantStateSave("data", hot.getData())`

**How to save data locally.**

You can save any sort of data in local storage in to preserve table state between page reloads. In order to enable data storage mechanism, `persistantState` option must be set to `true` (you can set it either during Handsontable initialization or using the `updateSettings` method). When `persistentState` is enabled it exposes 3 hooks:

`persistentStateSave` (`key: String`, `value: Mixed`) Saves value under given key in browser local storage.

`persistentStateLoad` (`key: String`, `valuePlaceholder: Object`)
Loads `value`, saved under given `key`, form browser local storage. The loaded `value` will be saved in `valuePlaceholder.value` (this is due to specific behaviour of `PluginHooks.execute()` method). If no value have been saved under `key` `valuePlaceholder.value` will be `undefined`.

`persistentStateReset` (`key: String`)
Clears the value saved under `key`. If no `key` is given, all values associated with table will be cleared.

Comment: Yes, I did it. But do you know how I can use persistentState?

Comment: I'll update my answer with the quote from their site

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But I don't really understand where I can use these methods. For localstorage I just use `localStorage['data'] = hot.getData()`, but how do I use persistentStateSave method for example? On what object? hot doesn't have this method.